# What do I do with Deluca coins?

Tags: littlewood

I keep getting Deluca coins for leveling in various things - are these good for anything in particular, or can I just sell them for Dewdrops? I haven't yet figured out what they might be good for, and if I should keep them for something or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](https://littlewood.gamepedia.com/Deluca_Coin) for this game:

> Can be used in Port City Deluca's casino at the gambling machines to earn useful items.

That seems to be the only use for them.